# Simple C code in python --- switch statement

Tags: python, c++

I want to write this C++ code in Python:

```
cout<<"input number";
cin>>x;
switch(x)
{
 case '1':
   cout<<"my name is ali";
 case '2':
   cout<<"my name is hamza";
 default:
   cout<<"invalid input";
}
goto again:
```

I also checked the dictionary statement, but maybe I am coding it incorrectly.

Comment: http://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary like structure like this.

```
def my_switch(x):
    my_dict = {
            '1': 'my name is ali',
            '2': 'my name is hamza',
        }
    if x in my_dict.keys():
        return my_dict[x]
    else:
        return "invalid input"
```

Implementation of this function:

```
In [21]: my_switch('1')
Out[21]: 'my name is ali'

In [22]: my_switch('not a key')
Out[22]: 'invalid input'
```

Comment: But sir i want to take input from user :(... I changed your code: def my_switch(x):
    my_dict = {
            '1': 'my name is ali',
            '2': 'my name is hamza',
        }
    if x in my_dict.keys():
        print x
        return my_dict[x]
    else:
        return "invalid input"
y=raw_input("enter number:")
my_switch(y)
,,,,,,,,,,but it displays 1 instead of my name is ali... if i put digit 1

Comment: you can take input by, `x = raw_input()`. and I am not clear about the error you are getting. can you post your code?

Comment: yes i took it with raw_input check >>> def my_switch(x):
    my_dict = {
            '1': 'my name is ali',
            '2': 'my name is hamza',
        }
    if x in my_dict.keys():
        print x
        return my_dict[x]
    else:
        return "invalid input"
y=raw_input("enter number:")
my_switch(y)
,,,,,,,,,if i will enter 1 then it will display 1 not display 'my name is ali' ,,, i want to display value

Comment: remove the `print` statement in `if` block

Comment: i removed it also... but when user enter 1 then it should display... >> 'my name is ali' ......... ? so how to set it?

Comment: are you running the code I have posted here? please post your code in your question.

Comment: yes sir check this snap shot please.... http://prntscr.com/4b2r57 >> i am running your code... but i need to take input from user.... if user will press 1 then it should display 'my name is ali' .... that what i wanna do it

Comment: Thanks Sir I have solved the problem now >> check that final code >>> def my_switch(x):
    my_dict = {
            '1': 'my name is ali',
            '2': 'my name is hamza',
        }
    if x in my_dict.keys():
        return my_dict[x]
    else:
        return "invalid input"
y=raw_input("enter number:")
print my_switch(y)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, there are no `switch` statements in python:

```
options = {"1":"my name is ali","2":"my name is hamza"} # map responses to keys

while True:
    x = raw_input("input number") # take user input, use `input()` for python 3
    if x in options: # if the key exists in the options dict
        print(options[x]) # print the appropriate response
        break # end the loop
    else:
        print("invalid input") # or else input is invalid, ask again
```

Comment: Sir your technique is good... but your code is giving error on out put... can you please check it... and give me final form.... it will me more helpful please

Comment: I would need to know the error, if using python 3 change `raw_input` to `input`

Comment: yes sir please check the error... i have uploaded snap shot.... >> http://prntscr.com/4b2onl  >>> i am using python 2.7.5 not 3

Comment: Thanks sir,,,, i have also solved this >>> check final code >> options = {"1":"my name is ali","2":"my name is hamza"} # map responses to keys

while True:
    x = raw_input("input number: ") # take user input, use `input()` for python 3
    if x in options: # if the key exists in the options dict
        print options[x] # print the appropriate response
        break # end the loop
    else:
        print "invalid input" # or else input is invalid, ask again

Answer (score 0):

Python has no `switch` equivalent.

You can use if/else

```
if x == '1':
   print "my name is ali"
elif x == '2':
   print "my name is hamza"
else:
   print "invalid input"
```

If you are concerned that this may mean doing a lot of tests against `x`. You can often use a dict, with the keys being values of `x`. eg.

```
x_map = {"1": "my name is ali",
         "2": "my name is hamza"}

print x_map.get(x, "invalid input")
```

Comment: this does not loop again on invalid input, it  ends after a single pass no matter what

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, the version given just loops forever anyway. regardless it is in invalid input. I'm not sure why someone with much knowledge of C is using goto there anyway.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: this answer is already way better than what the question deserved.